# The best way to build cache

Tags: android

I have app that suits on Facebook, VK apps. I need to make a cache system to have offline access to some pages and improve a time of the data loading. I never make cache system earlier... So I very want to listen advices from people who built so systems. For example, how to save data better in database or in files. If it's database then where the best way to storage it in android app cache folder or use a simple built-in sqlite database... I will very glad to all answers by my theme.

Comment: what are you trying to store? Is it images or just text?

Comment: Images and text (json objects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cache items using the **LruCache** available in Android. [LruCache](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache.html)

As you are trying to save Json objects, then the effective way is to retrieve the Json objects using a network library such as `Volley` and save the Json String in a SharedPreferences file. And you can parse it to load into a View whenever you want! And you can cache the Images using the NetworkImageView of Volley with LruCache! This helps you to cache and populate images and texts trouble free ! The perfect tutorial is already available [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/)

Also, here is the [code](https://github.com/shaheenkdr/EduKnow/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/mobloo/eduknow/FeedsFragment.java) to my implementation as well!

Comment: Reply in the comment if you find any trouble! :)